# Do Build scripts wait for Command line tasks to complete before proceeding?

Tags: php, ant, build-process, phing

Sorry if this question seems vague, I am actually asking about the Phing build script in PHP which is built off of the Ant build script for Java but I assumed that other build scripts for other languages probably perform the same way.

I have built a PHP script that will optimize images, you pass the script through the Command line a file path to a folder of images and my script will recursively go through all the images and folders of images and run the images through another 5 command line tools to optimize the images depending on what kind of image they are.

- All images go through **ImageMagick** to accurately determine what kind of file they are
- **jpg,jpeg** images go through **JPEGTran**
- **Animated gif's** go through **GIFsicle**
- **non-animated gif's** get converted to png with **ImageMagick** and ran through **PNGcrush**
- **png** images go through **PNGcrush**, **PNGquant**, and **PNGout**

As you can imagine this take a lot of time, from some test so far, it can take anywhere from 5-15 seconds **PER Image** to run through the appropriate programs.

Now the whole reason for me building this is because it's awesome but secondly I built it with a Command line interface in mind for the sole purpose of being able to use it with my Phing Build script, which I have not wrote yet or even really learned all about yet.

So just a basic question for now, as I explained it takes a considerable amount of time to process images, will these build scripts generally wait/halt for a command line process to finish running before they finish there build process?

I just really want to make sure that if for some reason I had a folder full of images (ie 100 images) that could take a really long time to process, and I don't want anything to time-out and stop working

Comment: I would say it's configureable: background or not. So wait or pass a long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, build tools like ant or phing generally wait for a command executation to finish.

To speed up things considerably, given your machine has more than one core, is to use parallel execution which is at least available in ant.